# p4 Ztags formatting for queries with multiple response entries

Tags: perforce

Ztags filters work greatly but I don't know how to use them with ie. `p4 filelog` where I get many results and each entry has enumerated field like:

```
... rev0
... change0
... action0 
... type0
... time0
... user0 
... client0
... desc0
```

and then field name is incremented, so in the end I don't have consistent field name for formatting when I would like to see only change and description.

Is it possible to target a field like that across all counts?

Comment: Think of the numbers as index positions in an array, so when filelog (conceptually) returns you an array of data, the index numbers allow you to move through the array. Note that complex p4 commands can even return multidimensional arrays, so learning to comprehend this data format is valuable. Such data processing, of course, is best done in a full-fledged programming language, such as when you use p4python or p4perl.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want change numbers and descriptions, try `p4 changes -L FILE` as an alternative to `p4 filelog FILE`.  That gives you one message/dict per change, which is much more amenable to simple (stateless) scripting with the `-F` formatting option.

`filelog` output is complex enough (it contains nested arrays of individual revisions as well as their per-revision integration history, it follows renames, etc) that you'll need to write some actual code to do anything very useful with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started working on my own CLI wrapper for p4 in Nim language.

In the process, I needed to grok the weird ztag output that p4 gives. I wondered why it did not give an option to output JSON. So I started working on a ztag to JSON converter to use for my p4 CLI wrapper.

The ztag to JSON converter is open sourced at: https://github.com/kaushalmodi/p4ztag_to_json/.

I release its 64-bit Linux static binary builds here: https://github.com/kaushalmodi/p4ztag_to_json/releases

- [A test filelog ztag output in my test suite](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/p4ztag_to_json/blob/master/tests/p4_filelog_long_desc.ztag)
- [JSON file parsed from that ztag](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/p4ztag_to_json/blob/master/tests/p4_filelog_long_desc.ref.json)

*The ztag format is terrible and inconsistent (see my ztag test suite to realize why I say that), and I hope that Perforce moves to a saner serialization format like JSON to replace it.*

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 version perforce introduced [new argument -Mj](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/global.options.html?Highlight=-mj) which may help

From documentation:

> **-Mj**
> Formats output as line-delimited JSON objects, with non-UTF8 characters replaced with U+FFFD
>
> **Note** Use the -Mj option with the -z tag option. Otherwise the
> marshaled output might be invalid.

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.